# Kernel of a morphism of regular rings.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, modules

Let $k$ be a field and $f:  A \rightarrow B$ be a surjective ring morphism between smooth Noetherian $k$-algebras.  By smooth I mean that the module of Kahler Differentials $\Omega_{A|k}$ is a projective $A$-module (likewise with B).

Why must each $Ker(f_{f^{-1}[\mathfrak{m}]})$ be generated by a regular sequence, where $\mathfrak{m}$ is a maximal ideal in B?

The argument seems to boil down to two things:

**1)**  Notherian + Smooth $\Rightarrow$ Regular 
(Without deviating from my definition os smoothness, I don't see how this follows)

*More importantly tho*

**2)**  The kernel of a morphism between regular local rings is generated by a regular sequence.

*(I've looked at some theory on this but it always seems to take a big detour and passes through more general objects like (CIs) which I am neither comfortable with, nor need.  My main issue would be to kind a simple, possibly bland proof of this fact)*.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I'm confused by (2). Is the morphism supposed to be surjective?

Comment: yup Im refering to the same morphisms as in the first line :)
Don't worry I'll post my solition in the next couple days (I've solved it two days ago but haven't got around to posting my solution yet )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the thing about kernels in [Section Tag 00NN](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00NN). Namely, any minimal system of generators of the maximal ideal is a regular sequence and the kernel of a surjection of regular local rings can be generated by the first few elements of such a minimal system of generators.

For results on smoothness one can look at [Section Tag 00TZ](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00TZ) which gives an overview of results on smooth ring maps. A quick argument that smooth over a field implies regular when the ground field $k$ is algebraically closed and the residue field is also $K$ can be found somehwere in Hartshorne Chapter I.

Comment: Hey looks like you beat me to the punch, I was gonna post the solution here tommorow (after having worked out the detail myself today ahah, funny enough we have nearly the same references :P , thanks again tho :)